# Stop/prevent showing context menu in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, event-listener, context-menu, ol-interaction

I am trying to make the context menu in a way that I can control where to show and where not to show. The summary is like **I should be able to enable and disable** the context menu in OpenLayers 3.

I am using the below code for creating a context menu and it's working fine:

```
var contextmenu = new ContextMenu({
    width: 170,
    default_items: true,
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Center map here',
            callback: center
        },
        {
            text: 'Add a Marker',
            icon: 'img/marker.png',
            callback: marker
        },
    ]
});
map.addControl(contextmenu);
```

Now I need to **prevent right click/disable the right click**. I have tried with the following and not working:

```
    var contextmenu = new ContextMenu({
      width: 170,
      defaultItems: true
    });
    map.addControl(contextmenu);
    
    contextmenu.on('beforeopen', function (evt) {
      contextmenu.disable();
    });

    function center(obj){
      console.log(">>",obj);
    }
```

Any references on this?

Comment: If you are using the jonataswalker control you should handle that in the beforeopen event https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-contextmenu#events

Comment: @Mike, I have used as you suggested. Modified my code in question too. This too not disabling context menu. Thanks in advance.